# How come these two sums are the same? (Quiet terse, but please help..!)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm struggling this for about two days... Below describes the situation. I'm trying to prove the finite additivity of Lebesgue measure.

Define $\mathscr{B}=\{\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i) : -\infty<a_i<b_i<\infty\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Define $\mu(\prod [a_i,b_i))= \prod |b_i - a_i| \forall -\infty<a_i<b_i<\infty$.

Then $\mu$ is a well-defined function on $B$.

Let $\{V_k\}_{1≦k≦m}$ be a mutually disjoint finite sequence in $\mathscr{B}$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^m V_k = \prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i)$ and $V_k=\prod_{i=1}^n [u_{i,k},v_{i,k})$..

Then, $\forall 1≦i≦n, [a_i,b_i)=\bigcup_{k=1}^m [u_{i,k},v_{i,k})$.

By extending every edges of $[u_{i,k},v_{i,k})$'s (draw a diagram), i proved that:

$\forall 1≦i≦n$, [ there exists a finite sequence $\{c_{i,l}\}_{1≦l≦\lambda_i}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_i=c_{i,1}<...<c_{i,\lambda_i}=b$ and $\forall 1≦k≦m$, there exists $1≦p<q≦\lambda_i$ such that $[c_{i,p},c_{i,q})=[u_{i,k},v_{i,k})$].

Now, define $S_f=\prod_{i=1}^n [c_{i,f(i)},c_{i,f(i)+1})$ where $f\in \prod_{i=1}^n \{1,...,\lambda_i - 1\}$

Also, i proved that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^m V_k) = \sum_{f\in \prod_{i=1}^n \{1,...,\lambda_i - 1 \}} \mu( S_f)$.

*My question is* how do i prove that $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^m V_k)= \sum_{k=1}^m \mu(V_k)$???

Comment: I would convince myself with pictures and live with it! =)

Comment: @Pedro I'm really picky to just convince myself with pictures.. Actually, i can prove this using "Axiom of dependent choice", but if this direct construction can be proved, the existence of Lebesgue measure is just a consequence on Axiom of countable choice. It drives me crazy..

Comment: $\mathscr B$ is a semiring. Maybe that helps in what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Pedro If the existence of lebesgue measure is guranteed, then my question is immediately done since $\mathscr{B}$ is a semi-ring. Is there easier construction of the Lebesgue measure which only uses AC$_\omega$? And yes i know that $\mathscr{B}$ is a semi-ring, but i don't have any idea how that helps..

Comment: Could you explain clearly what you're trying to do/prove?

Comment: @Pedro I just want to prove the existence of a borel-measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose value of a k-cell is a "volume" , using only $AC_\omega$. Once existence of such measure is guranteed, then the question in my post is immediately done. There is a construction of such measure via Riesz-Markov Representation, which requires DC and this is clear. However, i want to prove the existence of such measure with only AC$_\omega$. So i have to prove the question in this post or prove the existence of such measure.

Comment: Doesn't this result state what you want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_extension_theorem ? (Observe that it also works on semi-rings)

Comment: @madprob I know the caratheodory extension theorem. But to apply the theorem, one must show that $\mu$ is a *premeasure*, which is finitely additive on a semi-ring. Anyway i proved the question in my post.. Thank you